# Transit time in Valence TGV

Tags: transit, train-stations

I will soon travel from the Narbonne to Bruxelles Midi on TGV.

My itinerary has a change of train in Valence TGV with just 14 minutes between the arrival and the following departure.

- First TGV will arrive at 10:01
- Second TGV will depart at 10:15

Since I will be traveling carrying a bike in a bag plus panniers and the ticket states that boarding the train is possible up to 2 minutes before departure, I wonder if those 12 minutes are sufficient to move between the platforms.

Comment: Has that been sold as a single ticket or as two tickets? Is that a TGV-TGV interchange, or is there a TER involved?

Comment: It is not "just 14 minutes". Is is 12 minutes more than you need.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella The OP has a TGV > TGV transit. The TER trains are regional running NE towards Grenoble, and don't go to Brussels-Midi/Zuid.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On such a connection, both your trains will stop at the same platform (4): it’s the only platform served by northbound TGVs stopping in Valence TGV.

So the only thing you’ll have to do is get off the first train and move along the platform to your coach. Note that a TGV can be over 400 meters long so it can be quite a hike when you have lots of luggage, but it’s all on the same level.

For many trains you can know in advance how long they will be (1 or 2 train sets, 8 or 16 coaches) and the order of the coaches. You will also have the information on screens on the platform, but it’s likely they will only show it for the second train once the first one has departed (some stations have the older “composition des trains” displays which show more than one train at a time, but there’s usually only one such display on the platform, and I’m not sure if there is one in Valence TGV). Note that occasionally they get it wrong and then the a big dance begins on the platform when the train arrives and people notice it’s reversed.

If your second train only has a single trainset (8 coaches), you can actually get onto the train anywhere and then move to your coach while inside the train, but this is a lot more cumbersome in the train than on the platform, especially if you have lots of stuff. Still, if push comes to shove, get on the train and sort things out on the way.

In short: 12 minutes is more than enough to not miss your train and should be enough to get right at the door of the right coach before it arrives.

Comment: I transited south bound at Valence TGV last week. Coach position for this single-set eight-carriage train was displayed on the platform.

Comment: @DavidRemembersMonica it usually is, but what I meant is that the main displays (LCD monitors) show it for the current train only, not the next one, so when you get off the first train you have to wait until it has departed to know the positions for the next one. Was your experience different?

Comment: There were no close-in-time trains (on that track) to mine, and only my train set appeared on the screen. I didn't stick around to see what was displayed after my train departed <g>.

Comment: This, of course, all depends on the trains being on time, arriving at the correct platforms and having the car configuration that are supposed to have. I haven't  been on a TGV in a long time, but unfortunately for German Bahn high speed trains (ICE)  performance in all three categories has degraded quite a bit deteriorated over the last 10 years.

Comment: In Valence TGV it’s nearly guaranteed that the two trains will stop at that platform. It would require very very unusual circumstances for platform 3 to be used (that platform is the only other one which _could_ be used, but the train would have to cross the high-speed through tracks twice to get to and from that platform — this is definitely not going to happen in normal operations, and if the situation is so bad they have to do that, OP has other problems). But of course running on time and having the train in the expected order are recurring problems.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what platform you arrive at and which type of train you actually come from/need to get

Valence TGV has two *clusters* of platforms [map](https://www.garesetconnexions.sncf/sites/default/files/migrate/station/plan-de-la-gare-sncf-de-valence-tgv-rhne-alpes-sud.pdf) :

- `1` and `2` : Above the rest of the tracks, mostly serves TER regional trains
- `3-5` : At ground level, are platforms used by TGVs

They are connected by a central concourse from which you can access all platforms

---

Looking at the SNCF [website](https://www.sncf.com/fr/gares/valence-tgv-rhone-alpes-sud/OCE87763029/departs-arrivees/gl/arrivees) :

- Most TGVs will use platform 4
- All TERs will use platforms 1 and 2

Looking at SNCF-Connect, it appears your itinerary would be from Nabonne to Valence and Valence-Paris both on TGVs

You can be quite sure you'll make it, especially if it's a same-platform departure.

If it's not (like for an interchange between 3/5 and 4), it's a matter of climbing up to the concourse, and then going down immediately to platform 4.

If the reservation is a straight Narbonne-Brussels, SNCF is quite sure you'd make it, and in case of a delay on arrival, they will figure out a way to get you to your destination

Comment: In the northbound direction, platform 5 is only connected to the (low-speed) line going to the Alps, not to the main high-speed line to Lyon and Paris. Source: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Valence_TGV#Plans_des_voies (platform 5 is the rightmost one on the plan); or check with OpenRailwayMap. And according to the table at the bottom of https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Valence_TGV , there are currently no TGV services at all that pass through Valence and continue towards Grenoble. So platform 5 would only be used in exceptional circumstances (e.g. if the main line is blocked).