TGV Transfer at Valence
We will be traveling from Paris to Marseille with a transfer at Valence, wondering on the difficulty of transferring, especially when super tired due to jet lag/time change.
I have an option for the train with one transfer or a direct train but it is much later. Just wondering how straightforward the transfers are.

Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/180735/135305

If both trains are TGVs, there is only one TGV platform in each direction, so since you won't be changing direction I think you will literally just have to step off the train, wait for the connecting train to arrive, move along the platform to be in the spot corresponding to your seat on the next train, and step back on.

It’s worth noting that if the two trains run with two trainsets one may have to move up or down the platform (and it’s always easier to be close to the entrance of the appropriate coach of the departing train before it arrives anyway: it’s easier to walk on the platform than inside the train, especially you have luggage). It may involve walking up to 400m along the platform, but that’s indeed all there is to it. No stairs, escalators or elevators involved in this case. There will be screens on the platform telling you where each coach is going to be.

Thanks, edited!

I made a similar transfer at TGV Valence (Brussels > Valence, then Valence > Barcelona) in 2023.
This station has two TGV tracks in each direction under the station: one pair of tracks (in the center) is for through trains that do not stop, and have no passenger platforms. The other pair of tracks (on the outside) is for trains that do stop at the station, and have passenger platforms. Thus, both the OP's southbound trains will stop at Valence at the same platform. But because all southbound trains that stop will use the same track and platform, the two TGV trains may not be in the station at the same time.
It's worth noting that the station itself is several stories above the tracks, and there are no services at the platform level, only a few benches. If the time between trains is long, the OP might consider retreating up into the station, or, in the alternative, might choose the direct (but later) no-transit connection.
